# Apache - Serve directories from document root without putting in document root

Tags: apache-2.2

Right now, I have my DocumentRoot set to `/var/www/html` and my URL is `domain.com`.

My logical ordering of things is that I have mainpages for `domain.com` all located in `/var/www/html/{index.html,about.html,...}`. I also have "unrelated" sub-sites which I'd like to link from `domain.com/subsite1` `domain.com/subsite2`.

Is there any way I can move the `domain.com` top-pages to a folder, without having to move `subsite1` and `subsite2` inside that folder. I also don't want to hard-code any aliases to subsites or to the top-pages of my domain.

Essentially, I want to collect the scattered html files in my DocumentRoot into a folder, but still have them accessible without the URL containing a directory. I also want existing subdirectories of my DocumentRoot to stay where they are and retain the same URL.

Comment: Maybe something like telling Apache, "if it is not found in DocumentRoot, look here"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have tow options, one change the URL internally within the server, and the rest of the internet doesn't know it's been changed, and other redirect all requests to the new URL(s).

For the first option you'd use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).
**Eg.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/page\.html$ /newdir/page.html [L]
```

Or a generic rule if file not exist

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /newdir/$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect all requests to the new URL(s), then you can use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

**Eg.**

```
Redirect 301 /page.html /newdir/page.html
```